# passing C# dictionary object to JavaScript through Razor (MVC4)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm passing dictionary to my view and I'm using razor to pass it to JS.

My Code :

```
var data = []; 
@foreach(var tmp in Model){  
<text> data.push([ @tmp.Key,@tmp.Value]); </text>
}
```

My problem is that the code after it won't work.
What am I missing out?

Comment: how does it look like in dev tools? I mean the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need the quotes around the values.

```
<text>data.push(["@tmp.Key","@tmp.Value"]);</text>
```

Take a look at the actual source (right click view source), and see if it's valid javascript or not.